# Is test etherchannel load-balance disruptive?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, etherchannel

Is this command disruptive or just a logical exercise of existing configuration?

```
test etherchannel load-balance int po3 <some mac here>
```

Platform is 6500 series, running IOS.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so far as I am aware.  All it does is simulate sending data and seeing which interface would actually be carrying the packets.

Granted this is to the best of my knowledge and I might be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Zack, I need to make sure it's non-impactful before I can execute though so I'll leave this open for now.

Comment: @AL, the command only runs the hash algorithm to see which member interface would be used for traffic.

Comment: @RonMaupin - thank you sir, and thank you again Zack for reaching out, flagging as correctly answered!